# Reshape levels of a column (long) into new columns (wide)

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to take the levels of a column in one DF and add each level as a new column in a new DF. Here is a toy dataset showing the source and ideal target DFs.

Source DF

```
person  hour  ride 
Bill     1      A
Sue      2      B
Bob      1      C
Jill     3      B
Dan      3      A
Tina     3      A
```

Mapped DF

```
hour   A   B   C   Saturation 
1      1   0   1     .66
2      0   1   0     .33
3      1   1   0     .66
```

Here is a test data set:

```
test_data <- cbind.data.frame(person = c('Bill', 'Sue', 'Bob', 'Jill', 'Dan', 'Tina'),
                              hour = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)),
                              ride = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'))

test_data$person <- as.character(test_data$person)
```

See how each ride in `Source` turns into a new column in `Mapped`. I can get levels and use them to create a mapped DF via

```
new_data <- cbind.data.frame(hour = levels(test_data$hour))
```

but it all fails when I try to iterate through levels to add new columns. I see the levels.

```
unlist(lapply(levels(test_data$ride), function(x) paste(x)))
```

yields

```
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

So how to go through the levels in `$ride` and add a column in the mapped DF?

Bonus: I am going to run through each of the rows in `test_data` and `ifelse()` a `1` in the column that corresponds to that ride to show it had a rider, and a `0` otherwise, but someone must see how to do this more elegantly? As it stands, I would need an `ifelse` for every column extracted from the levels in `$ride` which I know has to be more verbose than required.

Comment: That's great. I hadn't seen recast. That said, I also never found it looking for questions adding columns so perhaps the question is useful as a pointer.

Comment: `pmin(with(test_data, table(hour, ride) ), 1)` maybe?

Comment: Why are you using `cbind.data.frame`? Use `data.frame` to create data frames

Comment: Add margins to a table with `round(addmargins(+(table(test_data[-1]) > 0), 2, FUN=mean), 2)`. You'd have to decide if tables are acceptable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)

mydat <- recast(test_data,hour~ride)
mydat
```

> ```
>   hour A B C
> 1    1 1 0 1
> 2    2 0 1 0
> 3    3 2 1 0
> ```

```
# 2nd part
for(i in 2:ncol(mydat)){
  for(ii in 1:nrow(mydat)){
    if(mydat[ii,i] > 0) {mydat[ii,i] <- 1}
  }
}
```

> ```
>   hour A B C
> 1    1 1 0 1
> 2    2 0 1 0
> 3    3 1 1 0
> ```

Comment: So the only need now is to turn the vales on A, B, etc from a range of 0..n to 0,1 where it's 1 if the value is > 0

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on recast, @Hack-R. I could write the for loops myself as well, but wanted a vector solution as I always try to avoid the (to me) obvious for loop approach. `ifelse` at least falls into that, but i still have to write one for each column coming out of `ride`.

Comment: I love recast. There is also perhaps one caveat here. My original question was how to add columns based on the levels in `ride`. There might be levels with no corresponding rows in the original df. I need to have each `level` represented because the percent of total rides ridden depends on the full range of levels, not on the possibly smaller subset of rides ridden.

Comment: @ShawnMehan Oh, ok if you want to update the question with an example like that then I can add it for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(test_data), hour~ride, value.var="person", 
               function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))[, 
        Saturation := round(rowSums(.SD)/3,2), .SDcols = A:C][]
#    hour A B C Saturation
#1:    1 1 0 1       0.67
#2:    2 0 1 0       0.33
#3:    3 2 1 0       1.00
```